# Go to previous page link in website

Tags: html

I'm trying to customize one of the tumblr themes and I have some problems with it. One of them is that I want to put a link on post pages to a previous page, just like in the picture: [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTWWE.jpg)

I tried, among other things, something like this:

```html
       <a class="acme-post-return -hide-index" href="/">&larr; Back to {Title}</a><br>
<a class="acme-post-return -hide-index onclick="location.href= document.referrer; return false" href="/">&larr; Go to Previous Page </a>
```

and I don't know how to fix it. That's how the page looks like with the code: [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE9T2.jpg)
It's in one line, < br's > doesn't help, and it doesn't re-direct to Tag Page either. 
My page is [here](https://themetestowe.tumblr.com)

I don't know how to put here my whole code because it's too long, so I'm just sending this:

```html
 .acme-post-return {
            position: fixed;
            top: 40px;
            left: 50px;
            display: table;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
```

Please help me, I just started to learing html and I am very bad at it :'( (also I'm so sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason they're in the same line is because you're positioning them both with the .acme-post-return css, which defines a fixed position at the top. You should wrap these two < a > tags in a surrounding < div > tag and position that div.

As for your onclick code, I would suggest using instead:

```
window.history.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, you directed me to the right path, I eventually used this code:

```html
   <a class="acme-post-return -hide-index" href="/">&larr; Back to {Title}</a> 
<a class="acme-post-return2 -hide-index" href="##" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;">&larr; Go to Previous Page </a>
```